# Optimize WPF ComboBox search with thousands items

Tags: wpf, performance, combobox

I have a WPF ComboBox control with an itemsSource of 66000 items. To improve loading performance I've used VirtualizingStackPanel and it's ok but now I've another problem.

The ComboBox is editable and when I type on TextBox it start search for SelectedItem to match...but it is slow and don't immediately respond to character typed.

How can avoid this behavior?

Comment: What are 66,000 items doing in a combo box in the first place?

Comment: It's a combobox with a customers list and there are 66000 items

Answer (score 6):

What Bruno basically said:

Read up on msdn more about it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx

Here's the code Note you'll need to add in your other bindings... :

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="VirtualPanel">
    <VirtualizingStackPanel />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>

<ComboBox ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource VirtualPanel}">
```

Or you can manually add it in ...

```
             <ComboBox VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using VirtualizingStackPanel only ensure that you will have **UI Vitualization** but in your case, as BoltClock probably wanted to point out, you might need to consider implementing **DataVirtualization** as well...

Answer (score 0):

Use `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"`
this will reuse the item containers instead create and discard the item containers and improve performance.